# How to restart minikube service using systemd

Tags: systemd, minikube

I have created below minikube service using systemd on my ubuntu machine.

```
[Unit]
Description=minikube
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service docker.service
Wants=network-online.target docker.service
Requires=docker.socket containerd.service docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/kalpesh
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/minikube start
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/minikube stop
User=kalpesh
Group=kalpesh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I would like to restart this service when minikube stops and shows below status.

```
kalpesh@kalpesh:~$> minikube status
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Stopped
kubelet: Stopped
apiserver: Stopped
kubeconfig: Stopped
```

The above systemd service still thinks that minikube is running however it has stopped internally. I would like to grep 'Stopped'.

Answer (score 0):

Does minikune API work?
If so you can just use `minikube start` which restarts the node.